# How to install exact php version 7.2.10 in Ubuntu?

Tags: php, ubuntu

I have a Laravel project that uses a specific library that uses php 7.2.10.

You will need to install php7.2.10 on your server (Does not work with the Laravel library, so will not install a new version of PHP).

I tried the following command but it doesn't work (I installed a new version of PHP 7.2.24 on the server, maybe I can remove it).

```
wget http://be.php.net/distributions/php-7.2.10.tar.gz
tar -zxvf php-7.2.10.tar.gz
cd php-7.2.10/
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/bin/php && make && make install
```

**I can´t use version 7.2.24 that is already installed in my server. I need 7.2.10 version**

Comment: What's not working with those commands? (Assuming you're running them as root). Sidenote, installing PHP from source is a bit of a pain and needs a lot of googling

Comment: i'm really newbie in server configurations. When i run that commands, i check my installed PHP versions and i have php7.1 and php7.2. I enable php7.2 with a2enmod php7.2 but when i check my current version with php -v i get 7.2.24 and not 7.2.10. Maybe i'm forgetting something

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/configure.about.php has details on all available configure parameters. You could configure as FPM (--enable-cgi), or as a shared apache module (--with-apxs2[=FILE]) among other options. In either case you need to properly configure apache to use the new module/cgi service

Answer (score 0):

Try diabling unwanted php versions

```
sudo a2dismod php7.2.24
```

and enable the version you need

```
sudo a2enmod php7.2.10
```

Comment: Hi! That down't work. I can disable php7.2 but not 7.2.24, i get ERROR: Module php7.2.24 does not exist!

Answer (score 0):

Finally i make it work. I completely remove php7.2 (In my case the installed one was 7.2.24) and then i repeat the command line steps:

```
wget http://be.php.net/distributions/php-7.2.10.tar.gz
tar -zxvf php-7.2.10.tar.gz
cd php-7.2.10/
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/bin/php && make && make install
sudo service apache2 restart
```

After that i enable new php version by

```
sudo a2enmod php7.2
sudo service apache2 restart
```