# Set default PHP version of apache2 to a specific version

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

Currently the PHP version showing if I call phpinfo() is 8.0.19.
I need to change it to 8.0.15.

I already build 8.0.15 from source and changed the CLI PHP version successfully by using `update-alternatives`.

**php -v**

```
PHP 8.0.15 (cli) (built: Jun  7 2022 10:21:21) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.15, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

But phpinfo still shows 8.0.19.

How can I set it to 8.0.15 globally?

---

I'am using Ubuntu 22.04

---

/etc/apache2/mods-enabled

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   36 Jun  1 14:30 access_compat.load -> ../mods-available/access_compat.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   28 Jun  1 14:30 alias.conf -> ../mods-available/alias.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   28 Jun  1 14:30 alias.load -> ../mods-available/alias.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Jun  1 14:30 auth_basic.load -> ../mods-available/auth_basic.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Jun  1 14:30 authn_core.load -> ../mods-available/authn_core.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Jun  1 14:30 authn_file.load -> ../mods-available/authn_file.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Jun  1 14:30 authz_core.load -> ../mods-available/authz_core.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Jun  1 14:30 authz_host.load -> ../mods-available/authz_host.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Jun  1 14:30 authz_user.load -> ../mods-available/authz_user.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   32 Jun  1 14:30 autoindex.conf -> ../mods-available/autoindex.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   32 Jun  1 14:30 autoindex.load -> ../mods-available/autoindex.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   30 Jun  1 14:30 deflate.conf -> ../mods-available/deflate.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   30 Jun  1 14:30 deflate.load -> ../mods-available/deflate.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 Jun  1 14:30 dir.conf -> ../mods-available/dir.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 Jun  1 14:30 dir.load -> ../mods-available/dir.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 Jun  1 14:30 env.load -> ../mods-available/env.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   29 Jun  1 14:30 filter.load -> ../mods-available/filter.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   27 Jun  1 14:30 mime.conf -> ../mods-available/mime.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   27 Jun  1 14:30 mime.load -> ../mods-available/mime.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 Jun  1 14:30 mpm_prefork.conf -> ../mods-available/mpm_prefork.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 Jun  1 14:30 mpm_prefork.load -> ../mods-available/mpm_prefork.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 Jun  1 14:30 negotiation.conf -> ../mods-available/negotiation.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 Jun  1 14:30 negotiation.load -> ../mods-available/negotiation.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   29 Jun  7 13:03 php8.0.conf -> ../mods-available/php8.0.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   29 Jun  7 13:03 php8.0.load -> ../mods-available/php8.0.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Jun  1 14:30 reqtimeout.conf -> ../mods-available/reqtimeout.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Jun  1 14:30 reqtimeout.load -> ../mods-available/reqtimeout.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   30 Jun  2 11:42 rewrite.load -> ../mods-available/rewrite.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   31 Jun  1 14:30 setenvif.conf -> ../mods-available/setenvif.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   31 Jun  1 14:30 setenvif.load -> ../mods-available/setenvif.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   36 Jun  2 08:38 socache_shmcb.load -> ../mods-available/socache_shmcb.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 Jun  2 08:38 ssl.conf -> ../mods-available/ssl.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 Jun  2 08:38 ssl.load -> ../mods-available/ssl.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   29 Jun  1 14:30 status.conf -> ../mods-available/status.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   29 Jun  1 14:30 status.load -> ../mods-available/status.load
```

/etc/apache2/mods-available

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  100 Mar 23 02:00 access_compat.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  377 Mar 23 02:00 actions.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   66 Mar 23 02:00 actions.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  843 Mar 23 02:00 alias.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   62 Mar 23 02:00 alias.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   76 Mar 23 02:00 allowmethods.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   76 Mar 23 02:00 asis.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   94 Mar 23 02:00 auth_basic.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   96 Mar 23 02:00 auth_digest.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  100 Mar 23 02:00 auth_form.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   72 Mar 23 02:00 authn_anon.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   72 Mar 23 02:00 authn_core.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   85 Mar 23 02:00 authn_dbd.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   70 Mar 23 02:00 authn_dbm.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   72 Mar 23 02:00 authn_file.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   78 Mar 23 02:00 authn_socache.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   74 Mar 23 02:00 authnz_fcgi.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   90 Mar 23 02:00 authnz_ldap.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   72 Mar 23 02:00 authz_core.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   96 Mar 23 02:00 authz_dbd.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   92 Mar 23 02:00 authz_dbm.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  104 Mar 23 02:00 authz_groupfile.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   94 Mar 23 02:00 authz_host.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   74 Mar 23 02:00 authz_owner.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   94 Mar 23 02:00 authz_user.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.3K Mar 23 02:00 autoindex.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   70 Mar 23 02:00 autoindex.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   64 Mar 23 02:00 brotli.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   64 Mar 23 02:00 buffer.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   62 Mar 23 02:00 cache.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  889 Mar 23 02:00 cache_disk.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   89 Mar 23 02:00 cache_disk.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   95 Mar 23 02:00 cache_socache.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   70 Mar 23 02:00 cern_meta.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   58 Mar 23 02:00 cgi.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  115 Mar 23 02:00 cgid.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   60 Mar 23 02:00 cgid.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   76 Mar 23 02:00 charset_lite.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   60 Mar 23 02:00 data.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   93 Mar 23 02:00 dav.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   83 Mar 23 02:00 dav_fs.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   79 Mar 23 02:00 dav_fs.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   68 Mar 23 02:00 dav_lock.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   58 Mar 23 02:00 dbd.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  460 Mar 23 02:00 deflate.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   84 Mar 23 02:00 deflate.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   64 Mar 23 02:00 dialup.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  157 Mar 23 02:00 dir.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   58 Mar 23 02:00 dir.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   64 Mar 23 02:00 dump_io.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   60 Mar 23 02:00 echo.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   58 Mar 23 02:00 env.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   66 Mar 23 02:00 expires.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   72 Mar 23 02:00 ext_filter.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   89 Mar 23 02:00 file_cache.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   64 Mar 23 02:00 filter.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   66 Mar 23 02:00 headers.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  176 Mar 23 02:00 heartbeat.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  182 Mar 23 02:00 heartmonitor.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.3K Mar 23 02:00 http2.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   62 Mar 23 02:00 http2.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   62 Mar 23 02:00 ident.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   68 Mar 23 02:00 imagemap.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   82 Mar 23 02:00 include.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  402 Mar 23 02:00 info.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   60 Mar 23 02:00 info.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  116 Mar 23 02:00 lbmethod_bybusyness.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  116 Mar 23 02:00 lbmethod_byrequests.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  114 Mar 23 02:00 lbmethod_bytraffic.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  114 Mar 23 02:00 lbmethod_heartbeat.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  121 Mar 23 02:00 ldap.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   60 Mar 23 02:00 ldap.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   70 Mar 23 02:00 log_debug.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   76 Mar 23 02:00 log_forensic.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   58 Mar 23 02:00 lua.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   62 Mar 23 02:00 macro.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   56 Mar 23 02:00 md.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7.6K Mar 23 02:00 mime.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   60 Mar 23 02:00 mime.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  120 Mar 23 02:00 mime_magic.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   72 Mar 23 02:00 mime_magic.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  668 Mar 23 02:00 mpm_event.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  106 Mar 23 02:00 mpm_event.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  571 Mar 23 02:00 mpm_prefork.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  108 Mar 23 02:00 mpm_prefork.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  836 Mar 23 02:00 mpm_worker.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  107 Mar 23 02:00 mpm_worker.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  724 Mar 23 02:00 negotiation.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   74 Mar 23 02:00 negotiation.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  855 May 17 18:49 php8.0.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  101 May 17 18:49 php8.0.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  822 Mar 23 02:00 proxy.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   62 Mar 23 02:00 proxy.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   87 Mar 23 02:00 proxy_ajp.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  347 Mar 23 02:00 proxy_balancer.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  115 Mar 23 02:00 proxy_balancer.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   95 Mar 23 02:00 proxy_connect.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   95 Mar 23 02:00 proxy_express.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   89 Mar 23 02:00 proxy_fcgi.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   93 Mar 23 02:00 proxy_fdpass.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  189 Mar 23 02:00 proxy_ftp.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   87 Mar 23 02:00 proxy_ftp.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   93 Mar 23 02:00 proxy_hcheck.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.5K Mar 23 02:00 proxy_html.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   97 Mar 23 02:00 proxy_html.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   89 Mar 23 02:00 proxy_http.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   97 Mar 23 02:00 proxy_http2.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   89 Mar 23 02:00 proxy_scgi.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   91 Mar 23 02:00 proxy_uwsgi.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   97 Mar 23 02:00 proxy_wstunnel.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   85 Mar 23 02:00 ratelimit.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   70 Mar 23 02:00 reflector.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   68 Mar 23 02:00 remoteip.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.2K Mar 23 02:00 reqtimeout.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   72 Mar 23 02:00 reqtimeout.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   66 Mar 23 02:00 request.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   66 Mar 23 02:00 rewrite.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   58 Mar 23 02:00 sed.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   66 Mar 23 02:00 session.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   99 Mar 23 02:00 session_cookie.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   99 Mar 23 02:00 session_crypto.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   93 Mar 23 02:00 session_dbd.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.3K Mar 23 02:00 setenvif.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   68 Mar 23 02:00 setenvif.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   78 Mar 23 02:00 slotmem_plain.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   74 Mar 23 02:00 slotmem_shm.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   74 Mar 23 02:00 socache_dbm.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   84 Mar 23 02:00 socache_memcache.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   78 Mar 23 02:00 socache_redis.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   78 Mar 23 02:00 socache_shmcb.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   66 Mar 23 02:00 speling.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.1K Mar 23 02:00 ssl.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   97 Mar 23 02:00 ssl.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  749 Mar 23 02:00 status.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   64 Mar 23 02:00 status.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   72 Mar 23 02:00 substitute.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   64 Mar 23 02:00 suexec.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   70 Mar 23 02:00 unique_id.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  324 Mar 23 02:00 userdir.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   66 Mar 23 02:00 userdir.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   70 Mar 23 02:00 usertrack.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   74 Mar 23 02:00 vhost_alias.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   66 Mar 23 02:00 xml2enc.load
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
sudo a2dismod php8.0.19
sudo a2enmod php8.0.15
```

It should work, or see [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/149039/how-to-change-what-version-of-php-apache2-uses).

Edit:
Considering there's no specific module for 8.0.x version for apache, it seems that you have to purge php, and install only the desired 8.0.15 version, as someone did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59061160/how-to-install-exact-php-version-7-2-10-in-ubuntu). Although that would solve your problem (most likely, not tested), it would remove php8.0.19 from your system, so if you need it for any other thing, you'd have to take that into consideration.

Comment: ERROR: Module php8.0.19 does not exist!

Comment: What's inside the /etc/apache2/mods-enabled folder ?

Comment: Alright, regarding your edit, have you tried ```sudo a2dismod php8.0 sudo a2enmod php8.0``` ?

Comment: It would not make any sense to disable and enable the same extension?

Comment: True, I thought for a sec that it could depend on your php active version, but that'd not make any sense. What do you have in your /etc/apache2/mods-available folder ? Any variation of php8.0.conf ?

Comment: Seems like you only have 1 module available for php8.0, which should correspond to the one from php8.0.19, maybe try to look on how to have a module for a very specific version of php. I can't seem to find anything for now about that, looking at it rn ;)

Comment: Ok, seems like there's no specific version for the libphp8.0, so what I would try if you really need php8.0.15 is to purge php, then reinstall only the 8.0.15. Doing so would remove php8.0.19 from your system, so if you need it for other things that might not be a great idea. Sorry, I don't have any better answer for now, gl mate! See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59061160/how-to-install-exact-php-version-7-2-10-in-ubuntu) kinda represents what I just said.

Comment: Does not work, apache2 only supports the latest stable, so im forced to use 8.0.19

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble using a2dismod / a2enmod for changing the php version.  Do it manually.
Deleting the link and setting a new link in /etc/apache2/conf-enabled made it work.
E.g. from 7.4 to 8.1

```
$ cd /etc/apache2/conf-enabled
$ rm php7.4-fpm.conf
$ ln -s ../conf-available/php8.1-fpm.conf
```